# Polymer core element animation imperatively

Tags: polymer

Using Get following javascript error when using polymer core element animation imperatively .  what am I missing?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CoreAnimation is not defined

```
var fadein = new CoreAnimation();
fadein.duration = 1000;
fadein.keyframes = [
  {opacity: 0},
  {opacity: 0.3},
  {opacity: 1}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stupid question, but did you include `core-animation.html`?

```
<link rel="import" href="components/core-animation/core-animation.html">
```

When do you try to programatically create your `CoreAnimation` instance?
If you do it too early it might be that it hasn't been initialized yet.

Try this:

```
<script>
      // Wait for 'polymer-ready'. Ensures the element is upgraded.
      window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
        var animation = new CoreAnimation();
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks yes had import included so that was not the problem. Issue was not waiting for polymer ready.